# Django : Write a session data to a file and let the user download the data

Tags: python, django

Need Help on how to write session contents to a file in static directory in django, so that it can be served to the user.

I have some huge session data. I want to store it in a file. Then serve it back to user.

I have no idea how to do it. Can you please help me on this ?

Thanks,
Bala.

@ mastazi, i did all research and without any luck came to SOF.

Here is a peiece of code i tried .

```
xml = request.session.get('content')
fileName = request.session['search'] + '.xml'
path = (/pathto/file/)

response = HttpResponse(FileWrapper(xml.read()), content_type='text/xml')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s'%fileName
```

I even tried to write the file to static folder ..
Then tried to access it directly. Its not working. There is some issue. I tried redirecting the output to the file path. But nothing works.

THanks

Comment: Friendly advice: here on stackoverflow you are supposed to do a bit of research, try something and describe what have you tried so far in your question.

Comment: @mastazi, yes i did research and only then i am asking..

Comment: So what exact problems are you having? What happens when you use the above code?

Comment: Nothing happens, UNable to download the file if i point it directly. Else if i use the FireWrapper method, i get an error saying "nothing obtaind" in the browser.

Comment: can any one help me please ?